# SUMPRODUCT with Less than or equal to in ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have created a formula that can track deltas based on a type that is tolerant to sorting and filtering.

Currently I have to use the formula in each row of the table I have created and have tried to create an arrayformula version of the formula but an not having much success

[image: Image of Table With Tracking]

[Google Sheet With Table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n4xKL5QPjkA8D_9G-fGfZk0XCkWH9k7u4Bpyqv37sbE/edit?usp=sharing)

For the sake of clarity I created named ranges for the values in each column

I have a formula with the behavior I want. i.e. In column F entries before the date in same row of column C are added up such that type A entries are added and Type B & C are subtracted. The formula is consistent regardless of sorting and filtering.

When I try to make it in the form of an arrayformula I get errors:

`=Arrayformula(SUMPRODUCT(Amount,Date<=(C4:C),((Type<>"A")*-1)+((Type="A")*1)))`

error because of size mismatch

Comment: When using named range in your examples, I would make your sheet editable. Named ranges cannot be copied directly from sheet to sheet without importing the whole file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use `arrayformula` directly in your original formula because it would be ambiguous. (Though there might be alternatives altogether.)

`Date<=C4:C9` should simply mean cell-wise comparison but you want an array mapping on the 2nd operand with the comparison expanded to the whole range of `Date` for each cell in the 2nd operand. That is fundamentally not what `arrayformula` accommodates.

- *Other critiques: It's better to avoid spurious brackets for readability. In separate scenarios where you do want cell-wise comparison, remember to match range size.*

You can instead use [`map`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en) as follows.

```js
=map(C4:C,lambda(c,if(isblank(c),,SUMPRODUCT(Amount,Date<=c,((Type<>"A")*-1)+((Type="A")*1))))
```

Comment: @Argll Thank you. I will spend a good chunk of time learning how this works tomorrow and thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

The `SUMPRODUCT` function is not designed to work directly with `ARRAYFORMULA` for the operation you're describing. `SUMPRODUCT` operates over the entire range, not on a row-by-row basis as needed for cumulative calculations that vary by row. You can achieve the desired output using other functions such as `BYROW` along with `LAMBDA` to process each row individually.

Try this:

```
=BYROW(Date, LAMBDA(each_date, 
  SUMPRODUCT((Date <= each_date) * 
             (Type = "A") * Amount) - 
  SUMPRODUCT((Date <= each_date) * 
             (Type <> "A") * Amount)
))
```

- `BYROW(Date, ...)` means we're going to perform a calculation for each
  date in the `Date` named range, which corresponds to `C4:C9`.
- The `LAMBDA` function defines a custom calculation that takes input parameters and computes a result. In this case, the `LAMBDA(each_date, ...)` part means that for each date in the `Date` range, we'll refer to the current date as `each_date` in our calculation.
- the asterisk `*` is used as the multiplication operator.